# Add wordpress shortcode to header.php

Tags: php, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

I have 6 pages and I would like to add a different shortcode to the header of each page.

Is there any way to add the icon shortcode before the page header h1 - but specific to each page name or id?

The shortcode is:

```
[icon enable_animation="true" color="Accent-Color" animation_speed="Slow" icon_size="" animation_delay="" image="basic_rss.svg"]
```

I tried adding the below code to the `page-sidebar.php` but it places it directly below the header in it's own row, rather than in it. It's also not page specific.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[icon enable_animation="true" color="Accent-Color" animation_speed="Slow" icon_size="" animation_delay="" image="basic_rss.svg"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Add wordpress shortcode to header.php** Use Visual Composer Short Code or Any Short Code You Can Use

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode-here]'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a different header file for each page Using get_header() will call the standard `header.php` template file; if you copy your header file to something like `header-one.php` (note the hyphen after `header`) you can call it with `get_header( 'one' )` then just change your header files accordingly.